# Get an array with characters and them ANSI colors from an input string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

This regular expression removes the ANSI colors from a string: `/\u001b\[.*?m/g`:

```
> '\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'.replace(/\u001b\[.*?m/g, '')
'Hello World'
```

How can we extract an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    start: "\u00\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231",
    end: "\u001b[0m\u001b[22m",
    content: "H"
  },
  {
    start: "\u00\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231",
    content: "e"
    end: "\u001b[0m\u001b[22m",
  },
  ...
]
```

What's the optimal way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the optimal way to to this?

Possibly not with regex, and I crashed my dev tools several times while building this, but here you go:

```
>>> str = '\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'
    re = /((?:\u001b\[.*?m)+)([^])([^]|)(?=.*?((?:\u001b\[.*?m)+)|)/
    var foo, bar = []

    while (null != (foo = str.match(re)))
      if ('' !== foo[3]) {
        if ('\u001b' === foo[2])
          str = ''
        else {
          bar.push({
            'start': foo[1],
            'content': foo[2],
            'end': foo[4]
          })
          str = str.replace(re, '$1$3')
        }
      } else
        str = str.replace(re, '$3')

    bar
<<< [{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'H',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'e',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'l',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'l',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'o',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'W',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'o',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'r',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'l',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'d',end:'\u001b[22m'}]
```

To handle strings like `'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello\u001b[0m\u001b[22m World'` also:

```
>>> str = '\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello\u001b[0m\u001b[22m World'
    re = /((?:\u001b\[.*?m)+)([^])([^]|)(?=.*?((?:\u001b\[.*?m)+)|)/
    var foo, bar = []

    while (null != (foo = str.match(re)))
      if ('\u001b' === foo[2])
        str = str.replace(re, '$2$3')
      else {
        bar.push({
          'start': foo[1],
          'content': foo[2],
          'end': foo[4]
        })
        str = str.replace(re, '$1$3')
      }

    bar
<<< [{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'H',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'e',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'l',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'l',end:'\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m',content:'o',end:'\u001b[22m'},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'',end:undefined},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'W',end:undefined},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'o',end:undefined},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'r',end:undefined},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'l',end:undefined},{start:'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231m\u001b[0m\u001b[22m',content:'d',end:undefined}]
```